# Generating non-repeating N-bit IVs, which are indistinguishable from randomness

Tags: protocol-design, random-number-generator, initialization-vector

I'm implementing a protocol which needs a 64-bit IV for every encrypted packet.  The cipher in use (AES-GCM, more or less as specified in [RFC 4106](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf)) does not require that these IVs are *random*, only that they are *not repeated* for any given key.  However, the *protocol* imposes the additional requirement that every byte on the wire be statistically indistinguishable from randomness.

What I need, therefore, is a PRNG that produces successive 64-bit numbers, and is guaranteed not to repeat itself until all 2<sup>64</sup> possibilities are exhausted.  I don't think this PRNG has to be cryptographically secure, but I imagine it would not hurt.  I would seed this PRNG at the same time as I generate the AES key (which is a short-lived session key) from a source of true randomness.

What PRNG algorithm should I use?

Comment: I question the soundness of that part: _the protocol imposes the additional requirement that every byte on the wire be statistically indistinguishable from randomness_.

Comment: @fgrieu I can imaging that if using some steganography scheme, which hides the whole protocol data inside the noise of other data (e.g. low bits of images).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Exactly. We don't want any patterns in the steg input that an observer could use to detect the presence of a covert message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the easiest way to generate these initialization vectors is to use a 64-bit block cipher (like Blowfish or DES/3DES), and encrypt sequential values of a 64-bit counter.

Of course, the "indistinguishable from true randomness" property of good block ciphers is only valid if the attacker can't observe much more than $2^{32}$ such initialization vectors, as then a truly random sequence would start to show duplicate elements, while your one would not, by your requirement.

Actually, if the only requirement is a nonce, and your protocol messages arrive in sending order (like over a TCP connection), you don't have to send it with the actual stream data, as long as the other side has the necessary information to generate it. Then a simple counter, counted up at both sides (and never transmitted), will do nicely (and you don't have to think about another key which needs to be managed).

Comment: Yah, the protocol requires rekeying after 2^32 messages for exactly that reason.

Comment: Ah, if you have that anyways, I think you can also use any cryptographic PRNG - the probability of repetitions is quite small before that. (You might shift the rekeying a bit earlier to be more on the safe side.)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the ANSI X9.31 PRNG based on AES. In this case the it must only repeat after $2^{64}$ because the underlying block cipher have a length of 128 bits. The other advantage of this PRNG is that it's too uses AES.

Comment: While the whole sequence of outputs of a PRNG will not repeat early, individual output numbers (128-bit blocks) as well as any 64-bit blocks derived from this will have duplicates earlier.